# Don't run 'npm install && bower install'

Tags: jhipster

I'm running 'yo jhipster' v3.10.0 and selecting the 'microservice gateway' type of application.

After answering the questions the files are generated then 'npm install && bower install' is run automatically.

Is it possible to tell jHipster not run the npm and bower installs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the --skip-install flag. Have a look at all command line options with `yo jhipster --help`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was after.  I'd looked at the help already so I'm not sure how I missed it.  Thanks much!!